# Notched boxplot using gnuplot 4.6

Tags: gnuplot, boxplot

I'm trying to create a boxplot in gnuplot 4.6 using the following code fragment:

```
plot "bfile" using 1:3:2:6:5:xticlabels(7) with candlesticks whiskerbars, \
     ''         using 1:4:4:4:4 with candlesticks lt -1 notitle
```

The file *"bfile"* contains information for creating the boxplots:

```
1 0.846441701336 1.85125834872 2.04139268516 2.52113611364 3.52595276102 A11
2 1.0 1.86332286012 2.01911131918 2.44521435143 3.31805158841 A10
3 0.937457841853 1.89899281522 2.1055068453 2.54001613079 3.50155110415 A9
4 0.76451090769 1.88649072517 2.12057393121 2.63447727016 3.6870828446 A8
5 0.881026437774 1.89209460269 2.10380372096 2.56614004597 3.57720821088 A7
6 1.05152952772 1.89209460269 2.04921802267 2.45247131934 3.29303639431 A6
7 0.750478015178 1.83250891271 2.07916616585 2.55386284439 3.63589374192 A5
8 0.602059991328 1.98677173427 2.50987376627 3.06929611397 3.69897000434 A4
9 0.47712125472 1.64095662126 2.04921802267 2.54499470961 3.67228262479 A3
10 1.0 1.7671400026 2.12057393121 2.61566342054 3.66020120138 A2
11 0.845098040014 1.73239375982 2.11727129566 2.72015930341 3.69731654173 A1
```

This successfully creates the boxplot as follows:
[image: Boxplot using gnuplot]

However, I want to generate *notched boxplots* which can be done very easily using *R* such as the following image:

[image: Boxplot using R]

Is it possible to generate a similar image using gnuplot?

Comment: No, that isn't possible even with version 5.0.

Comment: @Christoph maybe turn that into an answer with a pointer to the boxplot entry in the manual? (i.e. no evidence of notch functionality)